# Preserve YAML order perl

Tags: perl, module, yaml

I want to read data from a YAML file but I need the order of the elements to be preserved.

 Is there a module in perl which has this functionality and how to do that?

---

In response to  @mugen kenichi

I managed to do what I want but I don't believe that this is a reasonable solution.

old YAML:

```
foo:
   bar: some value
   baz: other value
qwe:
   bar: yet another value
   baz: again
```

new YAML

```
 -
   foo:
      bar: some value
      baz: other value
 -  
   qwe:
      bar: yet another value
      baz: again
```

Comment: If order is relevant you should use sequences in yaml. Rethink your yaml data structure.

Comment: Yes that is actually an ordered mapping as described here http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2765410

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***UPDATE***: [YAML.pm now supports order preservation](https://metacpan.org/dist/YAML/view/lib/YAML.pod#Preserve). See [this up-to-date answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72337076/14660).

The [YAML spec specifically states](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#key/order/) that "mapping keys do not have an order" and that "in every case where node order is significant, a sequence must be used".  To infer order from a mapping would be in violation of the spec.  Using ordered mappings, as mentioned by mugen, is the correct solution to preserve order.

If you *really* wanted to, you could somehow get a YAML parser to dump into a [Tie::IxHash][2] which will preserve order... but I know of no Perl YAML parser which gives you that level of control.  It's possible you could do something with [YAML::Old::Loader][3], but that is not a very good YAML parser and YAML::Old::Loader is not documented.

A third option would be to use explicit [YAML tags](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2761292) (aka types) to instruct the parser to load your mappings as a special type and then you supply the callback... but even then it's likely the YAML parser will supply your callback with an unordered hash.

I would suggest you simply change the YAML.  The point of a portable data language is that all the semantic meaning is explicit in the data file or the spec, not implicit in a particular parser.  Ordered mappings are an accepted, compact YAML idiom.

```
- foo:
      bar: some value
      baz: other value
- qwe:
      bar: yet another value
      baz: again
```

Comment: This is a bit outdated, since YAML::PP and even YAML.pm allow preserving order for quite a while now.

Comment: @tinita I've linked to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with [YAML::PP](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML::PP) since version 0.021.

```
use YAML::PP;
use YAML::PP::Common qw/ :PRESERVE /;
my $yp = YAML::PP->new( preserve => PRESERVE_ORDER );
my $data = $yp->load-string($yaml);
say $yp->dump_string($data);
```

(Disclaimer: I'm the module's author)

Answer (score 0):

It took some searching, but it is possible. Based on https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML::PP#preserve, I got this short script to read in the first file and print out the YAML on STDOUT. Data:Dumper also shows that the order is maintained.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

use YAML::PP;
use YAML::PP::Common;
my $yp = YAML::PP->new( preserve => YAML::PP::Common->PRESERVE_ORDER );
my $yaml = $yp->load_file( $ARGV[0] );
print $yp->dump($yaml), "\n";
```

Comment: please don't use the number 2 for the option. the `YAML::PP::Common` constants are there to avoid using numbers directly, because they might change in the future.

Comment: Is there a way to use the constant with `use strict;`? That is why used the value directly. If you could use a non-"bare word" variable option that would help with my code. And I am super happy that you have created this functionality!

Comment: Found a solution: ` YAML::PP::Common->PRESERVE_ORDER`, maybe you could mention this option in your documentation.

Comment: You have to import the constant. See my answer below. This is copied from the documentation.